# How would one allow a client to query a graph database in Smalltalk, without exposing all of Smalltalk?

Tags: programming-languages, query, smalltalk

Is there any example of Smalltalk being used as a query language?

What I am looking for is: a system or an application where the Smalltalk nature of the application is hidden or irrelevant to the end-user and portions of the language is exposed only for querying the object model underneath (be it application objects, document objects, a simulation or similar). For example a user interface where user defines queries in Smalltalk – either as the predicate portion of the query or the predicate + some other information entered through other user interface elements. The application then wraps it into blocks and applies appropriate filtering functions such as `select:` or `detect:` depending on the goal of the query.

Analogy would be SQL interface, however that would require relationship model to gain real benefits from it. I'm looking for a language use where the queried model is just a ad-hoc object graph.

[@JavierBurroni](https://twitter.com/JavierBurroni/status/534693608252002304) suggest "GemStone/S 64 Bit Programming Guide chapter 6" (actually [Chapter 7 in the 2012 edition](http://downloads.gemtalksystems.com/docs/GemStone64/3.1.x/GS64-ProgGuide-3.1.pdf)) as an example. Which is nicely explained, but still typical smalltalk use within the Smalltalk environment by the Smalltalk developers.

Is there a such thing?

Comment: off-site resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Answer (score 4):

.NET already does this; it's called Linq.  Linq is basically SQL for object collections.

In C#, it looks like this:

```
var q =
  customers.
  where(c => c.City == "Montreal").
  select(c => c.CompanyName);
```

and in Smalltalk, it looks like this:

```
q :=
  customers
    where: [ :c | c city = 'Montreal' ]
    select: [ :c | c companyName ].
```

or this:

```
((people
    select:  [ :person | person type = #adult ])
    reject:  [ :person | person location = 'New York' ])
```

To hide the Smalltalk representation from your users, you would have to create some sort of domain-specific language that is parsed and processed by Smalltalk. SQL is one such language, but it could be simpler than that.  It could merely be a wrapper around the Smalltalk semantics.

For an example of how this might work, look at the [Biosmalltalk](https://code.google.com/p/biosmalltalk/) project.

Of course, all this depends on having some sort of reasonable organizational structure to your data.  If your goal is to query data having an *arbitrary* representation, then you need to look into things like graph databases or dynamically-generated queries.

**Further Reading**
[Is C# turning into Smalltalk?](http://gnuvince.wordpress.com/2005/09/19/c-is-turning-into-smalltalk/)
[Your language features are my libraries](http://bitquabit.com/post/your-language-features-are-my-libraries/)
[Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)